# Как спарсить имя и фамилию из строки?

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

У меня есть столбец с именами, например `'Max Mustermann'`, и мне нужно спарсить `first_name` и `last_name`. Проблема в том, что иногда вместо имени попадается название предприятия, имена нескольких человек или имена состоящие из 4-5 слов. Нормальное имя должно иметь минимум 2 буквы. В этом случае я хотел бы получить `NULL` для `first_name` и `last_name`. Подскажите, как это можно сделать средствами SQL или PL/SQL (БД: Oracle 12.2)?

Пример входных данных:

```
NAME
Max Mustermann
Doe, John
Ursula von der Leyen
Рога и Копыта
J Li
```

На выходе хотелось бы получить следующее:

```
FIRST_NAME      LAST_NAME
Max             Mustermann
John            Doe
NULL            NULL
NULL            NULL
NULL            Li
```

Собственная попытка решения:

```
select 
  regexp_replace(name, '^([[:alpha:]]{2,})[[:space:]]+([[:alpha:]]{2,})$', '\1') as first_name,
  regexp_replace(name, '^([[:alpha:]]{2,})[[:space:]]+([[:alpha:]]{2,})$', '\2') as last_name
from table_name
```

Собственная попытка решения нормально отрабатывает для имен состоящих из двух слов. Если слов больше тогда и в `first_name` и в `last_name` попадает все исходное значение целиком.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не идеально, но почему бы не так:

```
select 
    regexp_substr (name, '^([[:alpha:]]{2,}),?\s+[[:alpha:]]+$',1,1,null,1) first_name,
    regexp_substr (name, '^[[:alpha:]]+,?\s+([[:alpha:]]{2,})$',1,1,null,1) last_name
from t
/
 
FIRST_NAME       LAST_NAME       
---------------- ----------------
Max              Mustermann      
Doe              John            
NULL             NULL            
NULL             NULL            
NULL             Li
```

Comment: спасибо! сейчас буду тестировать)

Comment: заменил `\w` на `[[:alpha:]-]{2,}` так, чтобы не учитывать цифры, но учитывать дефисы в именах - и стало прилично работать! Еще раз спасибо!! :)

Comment: @MaxU Да, с \w поспешил для краткости, поправлю. Главное идея, остальное можно доработать.